# Can't mount AFP and SMB shares through Finder but can manually mount via terminal

Tags: macos, mount, sharing, smb, afp

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 on a laptop which cannot mount or connect to any shares, AFP or SMB, through Finder. I can, however, connect through terminal bash commands and is able to mount them this way;

Once mounted through terminal commands, Finder can then browse the share.

This is just a problem on the one profile on that computer as other profiles do not have this issue. I have removed the keychains for the servers and still no luck through Finder.

I also checked and verified the disk and permissions. Any ideas what could be wrong with this profile?

Comment: Do you have an example of what happens when you try to connect? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same issue as I've seen try this:

Get rid of the user's GlobalPreferences.plist file (it's hidden).

~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist

Comment: I can't recall exactly, but you may need to log out and then log back in after deleting this file.

Answer (score -2):

workaround posted there for a very similar issue:
http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/24/workaround-problem-connecting-to-server-mac-os-x-lan-discovery-error/

Comment: Answers on AD should be more than just a link. Please include the essential part of the linked page into your answer to make it stand alone.